# Power BI show data between two dates

Tags: powerbi

I would like to show data between two dates. For example given the next table:

[image]

I would like to show in a bar graph, by month, every person who is included in that month.

For example, in 2018 January should appear only Kevin

In 2018 February should appear Kevin and Kate

In 2018 March should appear Kate and Morgan

And so on. The problem is how to do this, there is some documentation or some clude I can use to achieve it.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to show in a bar graph, by month, every person who is included in that month.

You can do this using a basic calendar table and a measure to work out if the calendar table date is within the start/end date range. The table doesn't need to have a relationship between the main table.

First create a basic calendar in DAX or M, this is a DAX calculated table one:

```
Date = Calendar( Date(2018, 1, 1), Date(2018,12,31))
```

You can use the built in date hierarchy but I prefer the month to be displayed as MMM-yyyy, so add a new column on the date table using:

```
Month = Format('Date'[Date], "MMM yyyy")
```

For the formula needed to count people in the months:

```
Example Count = CALCULATE(COUNT('Example Data'[Name]),
                          FILTER (  'Example Data',
                                    'Example Data'[Start Date]<= CALCULATE(MAX('Date'[Date] )) &&
                                     'Example Data'[End Date] >= CALCULATE(MIN('Date'[Date]))))
```

Which should give the following
[image: Example measure]

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

You could do this by altering the base data into a format where each month has a new row for a new name. This would make your final objective much easier. For example from the above sample data, the data for the name "Kevin" would be converted into something like:

```
Name   StartDate   EndDate   Month
Kevin   1/1/2018   2/4/2018  1/1/2018
kevin   1/1/2018   2/4/2018  2/1/2018
```

The following link highlights the steps which you should follow to achieve the above result:

https://medium.com/dm-p/generating-rows-by-month-for-date-ranges-in-power-query-9baf62ed8e99

Once the month value is created, then you can use the altered table to depict the data in the way you want. Hope this helps.